# Grabbing Contents of h4 in same container as "Remove Button" - jQuery

Tags: jquery, dialog

So, I have jquery spitting out containers with h4's inside. Each of these containers contains a "remove" button. When you click this remove button you get a jquery UI dialog confirm prompt. This prompt basically says:

Are you sure you wish to remove ((Contents of H4 tag)) ?

**Here is the html...**

> ```
> <div class="container">
>     <h4>Title of Item</h4>
>     <div class="remove">Remove</div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="remove-dialog">
>     Do you wish to <strong>remove the <span class="account-name">((Account Type))</span></strong>  account from
> ```
>
> your application?

```
**Here is my jQuery**
    // Remove Added Account and Subtract from Account count
        $('.remove').live('click',function() {
            var current = this
            var AccountName = $(this).closest('div').children('h4')
            console.log(AccountName)    

            $(".remove-dialog").dialog({
                buttons : {
                    "Yes" : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $(current).parents("div:first").remove()
                        Accounts--
                        $('.account-count').val(Accounts).change()
                },
                    "No" : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
              }
            });
            $('.remove-dialog').dialog("open"); 
        });
```

So what I want is to populate the ((Account Type)) with the h4 in the same container. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: or `$(this).siblings('h4')` ETA: I don't see where you are attempting to change the text for the dialog... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks!

var AccountName = $(this).siblings('h4').text()
$('.account-name').text(AccountName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ATraE/3/)?

it's this line that gets you to the title:

```
var AccountName = $(this).parent().find('h4').text();
```

this line sets the text:

```
$(".account-name").text(AccountName);
```

Comment: Bam! It worked, thanks so much guys. I used:

var AccountName = $(this).siblings('h4').text()
$('.account-name').text(AccountName)